# Compute with form to a domino document saved using datasource in XPages

Tags: datasource, xpages, lotus-domino

i have created a form with 3 fields and an xpage with 3 fields too. Each xpage field is binded to a form field using a datasource (datasource name: ds1)

I successfully create and save documents. When i click the save button i execute

```
ds1.save()
```

One of the 3 fields data type is Date/Time and i pass from the xpage a string like: dd/MM/YYYY (15/02/2014)
When i open the document in Notes client and go to document properties i see the field as Text List data type. If i double click the document and save it again, then in document properties the datatype changes to Date/Time, this is what i want it to be. Some kind of translation runs on re-saving it, maybe sth like computeWithForm...

The question is, how can i do this re-save in my code?

I have tried:

```
ds1.save();
ds1.getDocument().computeWithForm(false, false);
ds1.getDocument().save();
```

but it doesnt work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have two options.

1. Set the computeWithForm property on your datasource. Here's an example:

   ```
   <xp:dominoDocument var="ds1" formName="example" computeWithForm="onsave"></xp:dominoDocument>
   ```
2. Change your date/time field on your XPage to include a converter that converts the field to a date field (and optionally include a date picker):

   ```
   <xp:inputText id="dateField" value="#{ds1.dateField}">
       <xp:this.converter>
           <xp:convertDateTime type="date"></xp:convertDateTime>
       </xp:this.converter>
       <xp:dateTimeHelper id="dateTimeHelper1"></xp:dateTimeHelper>
   </xp:inputText>
   ```

Comment: I have set computeWithForm="both", shouldn't it work? about the second option, i have problems with dojo when i set it and i would like to avoid it.

Comment: Try adding the converter and not the dateTimeHelper and then save using ds1.save() (make sure you do not combine save using the "frontend" NotesXSPDocument and save using the "backend" NotesDocument)